# Is it permissible to watch Islamic TV series?

Tags: halal-haram

Series like Dirillis Artugul, Abdul Hamid where they show the lives of some great Muslim leaders. But the problem is do women coming into some scenes (not completely covered. The face remains uncovered.) and the background music make them haraam? And my intention is to only watch these series for their historical accuracy.
Thanks and may Allah bless you all.

Comment: First anything you may see on TV is presented spectator-friendly which means usually non-correct or fictional things are added. You maybe sure that whatever you may watch includes a more or less hugh part of incorrect presentation of facts and will be misleading.

Comment: It's a highly difference of opinion topic as you have already sub-topics that are having differing views like the face being awrah or music etc (many are covered on this site) .. some scholars have commented on the Umar TV series which is related to your question here . Have a look at references in "the Receptions from scholarly bodies" section on the site https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_(TV_series)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Because of woman are not covered properly in these series are not permissible to watch. Even if you see a full covered woman with hijab, still you should lower your gaze if you fell tempted for her.

Tell the believing men to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts, etc.). That is purer for them. Verily, Allah is All-Aware of what they do.

(https://quran.com/24/30?translations=18,19,22,85,84,101)

And If the background musics are used by haram instruments then it's also haram. I i recommend you to read books. or listen to audio books. rather than watching these series. Because sometimes the series are with misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

In Holy Quran Allah clearly says that:

**Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.**

Al-Nur Verse Number 30.

So keeping in mind the above verse of Holy Quran, we must avoid seeing the non-mahram's face whether live or on television. It is not permitted.

Comment: Hmm....but face isn't really part of the awrah